# Secure Data from Farm Admins and Database Admins

Tags: 2010, permissions, security

I am working with a client whose farm admins and database admins may not be approved to view information in one of the site collections due to governmental regulations. Therefore, he would like to encrypt the data in that site collection and restrict the ability of the farm admin to grant themselves rights to view / edit the data in that site collection. Is this possible?

The only thing that I could find on this topic was a suite of products from this company: http://cipherpointsoftware.com/. Does anyone have any experience with this company?